# Combine two dataframe into one dataframe ignoring null

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have below requirement in spark scala.

I have 2 dataframes:

DF1:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+--------------+
|id                       |sid1               |pid1           |sid2                          |pid2
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+--------------+
|                    1    |              1111 |           null|                      2222    |null
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+---------------+
```

DF2:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+--------------+
|id                       |sid1               |pid1           |sid2                          |pid2
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+--------------+
|                    1    |              null|           3333|                      null|     4444
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+---------------+
```

I want to merge these two dataframe and in result dataset only non null values should come.

Expected output:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+--------------+
|id                       |sid1               |pid1           |sid2                          |pid2
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+--------------+
|                    1    |              1111 |           3333|                      2222    |4444
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+---------------+
```

Both input dataframes(df1 and df2) will always have single record.

Also I do not want to hardcode column names in the logic because this needs to be implemented with dataframe having 200+ columns.

Answer (score 1):

I got this Java Solution working:

```
    List<String> cols = Arrays
                      .stream(leftDf.schema().names()).filter(s -> !s.equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
                      .map(col -> "coalesce(leftDf." + col + ", rightDf." + col + ") AS `" + col + "`").collect(Collectors.toList());
    cols.add("Id");
    leftDf.as("leftDf").join(rightDf.as("rightDf"), "id").selectExpr(JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(cols.iterator()).asScala().toSeq()).show();
```

I'll be adding Scala/Pyspark equivalent soon but the gist is join the two dataframes with aliases and call `coalesce(colFromLeft, colFromRight) as col` i.e. take the first non-null value between two columns